# Contour 3D of an array in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python it is really straightforward to draw 2D contour of a 2D array with the `contour` command.

```
      img=ones((4,4))
      contour(img)
```

I was wondering if something similar exists in case I have 3D arrays?

Comment: I guess you use `matplotlib`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, I do use matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `Axes3D` module, where you also find a [contour](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.contour) function.

From the docs:

> Axes3D.contour(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Create a 3D contour plot.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! But I need an array with x,y,z values for the code to be working. What I have is instead a 3d matrix.

Comment: Better always use `array`s when working with `matplotlib` instead of `matrix`. It's [recommended](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) to always do so. If you really need a `matrix`, you should convert it to `array` first.